# Pass pointer or PointerByReference in JNA for pointer argument in C

Tags: java, pointers, dll, jna

In C++ I have the following header file:

```
/** Default constructor */
CLPLIB_EXPORT Clp_Simplex *CLP_LINKAGE Clp_newModel(void);

/** Destructor */
CLPLIB_EXPORT void CLP_LINKAGE Clp_deleteModel(Clp_Simplex *model);
```

Trying to import this with JNA, I assume that I have to specify them as such:

```
public static native PointerByReference Clp_newModel();

public static native void Clp_deleteModel(Pointer pModel);
```

Is this correct, of should it be `Clp_deleteModel(PointerByReference pModel)`? Strangely, both seem to work in a very simple test, though the former does make more sense to me. I assume that JNA does some of its magic.

```
// option 1
PointerByReference a = Clp_newModel();
ChangeSomthingIntheModel(a,2);
Clp_deleteModel(a.getPointer());
ChangeSomthingIntheModel(a,2); // the JVM signals "illegal memory access here

// option 2
PointerByReference a = Clp_newModel();
ChangeSomthingIntheModel(a,2);
Clp_deleteModel(a); // passing the PointerByReference here! 
ChangeSomthingIntheModel(a,2); // the JVM signals "illegal memory access here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the CLP documentation, it appears that either `Pointer` or `PointerByReference` would work in this simplified example.

There are three general representations of pointers in JNA:

- The `Pointer` class, which has several methods for reading and writing from the pointed-to native memory.
- The `PointerType` class, which can be extended to represent a pointer with no other functionality, better if you don't need `Pointer` functionality.
- The collection of `<something>ByReference` classes, which are pointers to specific types of objects.

Since all you're ever doing is manipulating the pointer value, any of these would work: The more important point is that you pass a pointer object of the identical class that you retrieved from `Clp_newModel()` which is a pointer (to something you never deal with).

Note: this part of your code may not be doing what you expect it to do:

```java
Clp_deleteModel(a.getPointer());
```

The `getPointer()` method returns the pointer of the class, not the value being pointed to. There's no fundamental difference (except class type) between `a` and `a.getPointer()` in your usage.  (You might be meaning to use `a.getValue()` which returns the pointed-to value, which would be different, and probably *not* what you want.)

Currently you retrieve a `PointerByReference` so you have access (via `.getValue()`) to what's being pointed to, which appears to be a `CLP_LINKAGE`, which doesn't appear to be an object you'll ever manipulate. So you could retrieve a plain `Pointer` there (without knowing what it points to) instead.  And you would pass that same pointer to `Clp-deleteModel(a)`.

If you are never accessing the pointed-to value, you can simply use `Pointer`, however, it's generally a better practice for restricting the API, type safety, and self-documenting code to define a class extending `PointerType`.  In your case, `CLPSimplexPtr extends PointerType` would be a good choice.

If there is a need to understand the pointer value (the `CLP_LINKAGE`) that the returned poniter is being pointed at, then use the appropriate `<whatever>ByReference` extending `ByReference` and implementing the `setValue()` and `getValue()` methods.

Of possible interest to you, it seems there is a [`clp-java` project](https://github.com/quantego/clp-java) that implements `CLP` using `BridJ`, an alternative Java-to-native library (which uses JNA but has many optimizations for C++).  Their definition is `Pointer<CLPSimplex>` for both mappings, which would align with a `CLPSimplexPtr` class if you wrote it in JNA -- it's still a decorated plain pointer, but a type-safe one.

Comment: If I understand correctly,  JNA does do some magic. Pointer and PointerByrRference are treated as the same, if- and only if- they are used consistently w.r.t. the input/outputs listed in the C header file.

For my implementation I have to change some of the structure that clp-java has as of now. If I' m lucky (big if) I might be allowed to push this upstream. For the sake of exercise (my first project with a dll and Java 11) I am trying JNA first rahter than bridgJ :)

Comment: That's correct. Pointer by reference is 2 pointers, the pointer itself, and the value it's pointing to, which happens to also be a pointer.  But if you never use that pointed-to pointer, you don't need pointer by reference. (But it doesn't break if you use it, as you've demonstrated.)

Comment: I think your best mappipng is a `CLPSimplexPtr extends PointerType`.  Just a decorated pointer, but keeps type safety.

Comment: I have successfully implemented the latter. Not only because it is type-safe, but it also improves the readability of the code. Merci.